# Binding to DataGridView with an array of properties

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

Imagine a class `Item` with three properties:

- Item name (string)
- Quantity (int)
- Price (an array/list of class `ItemPrice` that has two properties: VendorName and Price).

Basically, I want to bind this class to a DataGridView where each row is of class Item. The problem is, there are a different amount of vendors (or can be edited later on) and the data binding must support this dynamic quantity of vendors.

Also, as a bonus, I want to add an extra column which displays a vendor's price multiplied with the quantity.

I do **not** want to use virtual mode (that's how I'm accomplishing this task at the moment).

Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to be able to edit the price list, or just display it?

Comment: Yes, I need editing as well. Should be a two-way binding.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be creating a string property on the class Item (or on a new class, or an anonymous class), and implementing this property to concatenate all of the vendors and item prices together.

The downsides to this are that it may look ugly to have all of the items in a string in the same column, and it won't be possible to edit the items in an intuitive way.

However, it would achieve the goal of showing an arbitrary number of vendors and prices, and you could easily add the vendor price multiplied by quantity to this.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an option. All values must be on their separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

you can map a table to a datagridview which is created dynamically.
here is an example code snippet:

```
    public class ItemBinding
       {
        List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();
        Item it = null;
        DataRow dr = null;
        public void mapping()
          {
                  for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
                     {
                      it = new Item();
                      it.qty = i;
                      it.name = "name" + i;
                      it.itemprice.Vendorname="vendor" + i;
                      it.itemprice.price = 20 * i;
                      itemList.Add(it);
                     }
          }
         public void binding()
         {
              DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                   dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("item", typeof(string)));
                   dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("quantity", typeof(int)));
                   dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("vendor", typeof(string)));

              //item list contains the detail of the class

                    foreach (Item c in itemList)
                         {
                            dr = dt.NewRow();

                            dr[0] = c.qty;
                            dr[1] = c.name;
                            dr[2] = c.itemprice.Vendorname;;
                            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                          }
                  dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                  dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                   }
          }
    public class Item
         {
            public int qty{ get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public ItemPrice itemprice { get; set; }
            public Item()
                 {
                   this.itemprice = new ItemPrice();
                  }
         }

          public class ItemPrice
            {
             public string Vendorname { get; set; }      
             public int price { get; set; }
            }
```

in this case itemprice is an has two properties which is nested or you can inherit it.
this may help you.